# How can I use a case statement in a make shell command?

Tags: bash, makefile

I've got two variables `foo` & `bar`, `foo` will have a value whereas `bar` may or may not. I want to concatenate them together, separated by a hyphen, if `bar` has a value. Ive got something that works in bash:

```
$ foo=foo
$ bar=bar
$ case "${bar}" in    "") echo $foo ;;   *) echo ${foo}-${bar}; esac
foo-bar
$ unset bar
$ case "${bar}" in    "") echo $foo ;;   *) echo ${foo}-${bar}; esac
foo
```

So far so good. Now I want to do the same thing in a Makefile using make's [`shell` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) but I can't figure out the syntax. Here demonstrates the problem:

```
$ cat Makefile
foobar = $(shell $(case "$${bar}" in    "") echo $${foo} ;;   *) echo $${foo}-$${bar};; esac))

default:
    echo ${foobar}
$ make
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `echo ${foo} ;;   *'
echo  echo ${foo}-${bar};; esac))
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `echo  echo ${foo}-${bar};; esac))'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

How can I concatenate two environment variables together in this way so that I can use them in my Makefile?

I am an utter noob when it comes to `make` so if I'm going about this in completely the wrong way then do let me know. thx.

Comment: Your first code can be simplified to `echo "${foo}${bar:+-}${bar}"`. I'm not sure about the second part: Are these actual environment variables, or make variables, or what? This whole thing feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are environment variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to run a subshell just to concatenate a few variables:

```
foobar := $(foo)$(if $(bar),-,)$(bar)

default:
    echo '$(foobar)'
```

should work just fine.

[Live demo](https://tio.run/##RY4xDsIwDEVnfAoPldJKhQNELRsSC5SBhSlyi6NWBILaBHH7YAqI7f/3nyy3NPUpdRRwvaML28ExVpUym@ZoFKwO22Z/0nhmS9EFAOt9SyPqGrNccpHlg5UorCiXZfFJAF9fw4K73qOa5fekYL4MwM@7HwMKrh/kIhtvjRQU6Q@kwFW@Aoi3iQP@ekov)

Comment: nice, thanks. Altho still don't get what I need. Suspect I'm hitting the same problem as I reported to AProgrammer, still just echoes an empty line. I guess echo in my target doesn't work like I'm assuming.

Comment: @jamiet Well, I know my code works (see the live demo link). I don't know what you're doing differently.

Comment: agreed. Me neither:( Thx for help so far, endeavouring to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Ohh...my dumb mistake. I didn't export the foo & bar variables. Now I have, and it works. Thank you.

Comment: of the two solutions posted here (from melpomene & @AProgrammer) this is the one I prefer, for obvious reasons. Thanks to AProgrammer for fixing my code and to melpomene for proposing something better.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide from Make the closing parenthesis in a variable like this:

```
cp=)
foobar:= $(shell case "$${bar}" in    ""${cp} echo $${foo} ;;   *${cp} echo $${foo}-$${bar};; esac)

default:
    echo ${foobar}
```

Comment: ok that makes sense, altho still doesn't work. I no longer get an error however it merely echoes an empty line.

Comment: Are you testing verbatim what we provide or are you using a more complex setup?  I guess it is the later case as this is working here.

Comment: My real scenario is of course different but yes, I am testing verbatim what you have put on here. Very strange. I'm on MacOS in case that makes a difference but I can't see that it would.

Comment: Ohh...my dumb mistake. I didn't export the foo & bar variables. Now I have, and it works. Thank you.

Comment: That is bananas. :D I've also seen someone give an example of saving the entire case statement to a var and doing $(shell ${command_str}). Is there really no simple way to just escape a right-paren in a case statement?